# How to delay custom code snippet execution in wix

Tags: delay, velo, delayed-execution

I have this code snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//form.ravpage.co.il/b7ca64ace3056e1fe11b3e16d52e58035DFCB665' charset='UTF-8'></script>
```

I added it to tracking tools and analytics and I tried to delay it's load using setTimeout, but it didn't work out.

I would appreciate any help, Thanks!